# PPTP client in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager, vpn, pptp

In Lubuntu 16.04 I have installed network-manager-pptp.  I then

- click the network manager icon
- click "VPN Connections"
- click "Configure VPN"
- click "Add"

But the "Choose a Connection Type" dropdown includes groups of Hardware and Virtual options, but no VPN options.

Can anyone suggest why?  On my Lubuntu 14.04 system the VPN options do appear as expected...